# Global vs local instances in Python

Tags: python

I'm a self-taught programmer without much CS background. I read a lot of discussions here about the topic of global variables in Python, but I'm still unclear about when the use of global is 'good programming practice'.

Let's assume I write a Python script that performs a couple of long computations on each sample in a folder. I create a simple class that holds the results of each computation, so once the script is finished I can print a summary file.

```
class SampleInfo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

    def add_sample(self, sample):
        self.dict[sample] = {}

    def add_value(self, sample, value)
        self.dict[sample] = value
```

I see 2 ways to write the main script:

A) Using the global statement:

```
import os

def LongComputation(sample):
    # do some stuff that results in a value
    Info.add_value(sample, value)

def main():
    global Info
    Info = SampleInfo()
    for sample in os.listdir("."):
        LongComputation(sample)

main()
```

B) Without the global statement, passing the instance to the function:

```
import os

def LongComputation(sample, info_instance=None):
    # do some stuff that results in a value
    info_instance.add_value(sample, value)

def main():
    Info = SampleInfo()
    for sample in os.listdir("."):
        LongComputation(sample, info_instance=Info)

main()
```

Especially when I have several types of Info classes and many LongComputation functions, option B) becomes very messy. On the other hand, using the global statement is discouraged.

Should I use B) over A)? Why?

Comment: I can't see any good reason to use global here. Can you give an example of when passing values around would be "messy" - and how that would be any messier than lots of global statements? 99% of the time, passing values is the way to go.

Comment: In the case where you suggest option B) will become very messy, don't you think it would be worse to have a whole host of globals with difficult to track down side-effects and impossible to follow control flow?

Comment: With "messy" I mean "much more code", as each function call might involve passing several different types of Info instances around. Also, when I'm having nested function calls and I add a new type of Info class I need to add the instance passing to each level of the nested functions.

Comment: Or am I just lazy and bring myself into trouble down the road? ;)

Comment: "Or am I just lazy and bring myself into trouble down the road?" This. Step 1: Try writing a large application just using globals like you describe. Step 2: When you are done, try and add some new functionality. Step 3: Break down and cry.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I guess this is the heart of the matter. Probably I don't have enough painful experience with large application to see that what looks like an easy solution for small scripts is actually a bad idea in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need to use a global here, you can just compute and return the value before adding it to the `Info` object. Also the class is overkill when a simple dictionary works just fine.

```
import os

def LongComputation(sample):
    # do some stuff that results in a value
    return value

def main():
    Info = {}
    for sample in os.listdir("."):
        Info[sample] = LongComputation(sample)

main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are correct that the class is overkill here, but the example I provided is much simpler than the script I'm actually writing. Maybe I didn't make that clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

When to use globals:

1. when it's a constant
2. when it's a singleton
3. when it's a private cache

And maybe, when your script is a quick, throwaway hack ;-)